# How to create a non-accessible controller action?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In one of my controllers, i use codeigniter's form validation helper. One of my validation rules is a custom function that i created that returns true or false.
Problem is, that this validation function is declared inside the controller's class. How do i prevent users from browsing to my validation function as a controller action (mysite/mycontroller/my_callback_func)?

P.S. - Tried to set the function as private but I'm getting an error that it's not accessible for the validation helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start the function/method name with an underscore.

Straight out of `./system/core/CodeIgniter.php`:

```
/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Security check
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  None of the functions in the app controller or the
 *  loader class can be called via the URI, nor can
 *  controller functions that begin with an underscore
 */
    $class  = $RTR->fetch_class();
    $method = $RTR->fetch_method();

    if ( ! class_exists($class)
        OR strncmp($method, '_', 1) == 0
        OR in_array(strtolower($method), array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods('CI_Controller')))
        )
    {
        show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
    }
```

Comment: This is how I do it also and works just fine. It is also outlined in the documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#private

Answer (score 1):

simply define your function **private** and put an **uderscore** befor the function name for example :

```
class Some_class extends CI_Controller{

     private function _some_method(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would instead make it a helper function. To do so, put a file in your `system/application/myval_helper.php`, then add your function in there. Then just call:

```
$this->load->helper('myval');
```

And you'll be able to access the function. Another alternative is to simply use `.htaccess` to block that exact URL.